# There is no available cipher algorithms in encfs

Tags: encryption, openssl, fuse

I'm trying to use encfs algorithm on my linux(ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS). and I have built source codes, and When I use encfs order, I can't see available cipher algorithms.

I can see

```
mirage@mirage-System-Product-Name:/usr/local/bin$ encfs ~/test ~/test2Creating new encrypted volume.
Please choose from one of the following options:
enter "x" for expert configuration mode,
enter "p" for pre-configured paranoia mode,
anything else, or an empty line will select standard mode.
?> 

Standard configuration selected.
Sorry, unable to locate cipher for predefined configuration...
Falling through to Manual configuration mode.
The following cipher algorithms are available:

Enter the number corresponding to your choice:
```

and during ./configure, checking for OPENSSL... no
so, I guess It's because of OPENSSL. But I don't know How can I solve this problem. Anyone have idea? or Anyone know how to remove older OPENSSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
I removed openssl by 'apt-get remove openssl' but, the openssl directory is still remained in /usr/local. so I removed the directory as well.
and I built openssl other version. (I don't know if it was version problem or not)
and the problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you built encfs without openssl. Encfs uses the algorithms built into openssl - you'll have to make sure that openssl is installed on your machine, and that the Encfs build process can correctly find the libraries.

See [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/encfs/issues/detail?id=59) for someone with the same problem.

You might want to run

```
apt-get install openssl
```

before installing encfs.

Comment: I guess the problem is because of wrong OPENSSL version.. So I want to remove OPENSSL and then install other version. But I don't know how to remove older OPENSSL.